# SQL Server 'Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server' after patching

Tags: sql-server

One of our servers went for a reboot last night after doing OS and SQL Server patching (SQL Server 2016 latest CU). Since then any call to a linked server from the patched server fails with the above error.

Other servers can still connect to the patched server, just outbound doesn't seem to work at all.

We also have an issue with the SQL Server Browser service wont start "stopped unexpectedly", although not sure if its related

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: SQL is a _language_, SQL-2016 is the current ISO/ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: SQL Server Native Client 11.0 only ever supported up to SQL Server 2012 in the first place and never supported features available on SQL Server 2014 and 2016. Ref: [SNAC lifecycle explained](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/snac-lifecycle-explained/ba-p/385381).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft OLEDB Providers - part of the SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) are deprecated:

- SQLNCLI10
- SQLNCLI11

You need to install Microsoft OLE DB **Driver** for SQL Server:

- MSOLEDBSQL

The switch happened in 2018. You can read about it here:

- [Announcing the new release of OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server)
- [Released: Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlnativeclient/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Ok people, problem solved.

One of the updates tried to upgrade the OLEDB connectors, ran into a problem and bailed. It had already deleted the DLLs for the drivers though.

Finding the drivers on the Dev server and copying them across solved the issue.

For those bleeding on about SNAC on being on SQL12, that was it's release version. It's been a staple ever since and is installed as standard by SQL16. It's not untill 2022 that it's replaced